# Chrome WebSocket returns "unexpected error 200"

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

It looks like a WebSocket creation problem, which should not be happening with chrome.
I tested it with different browsers (including chrome) from different machines (same OS same NW config) and it was OK.

How is this even possible?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mork; I'll check the versions though it does seem unlikely. The server side is an old version of node.js and IIS8. It fails on both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with a similar issue with chrome and safari about 3 years ago.
In my case it was, at the end, an issue of WebSockets versions

Basically there were [2 main protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support) of WebSockets: Hixi and Hybi, Hybi becoming the successor

You mentioned that with the same config one chrome browser works and one gives you that error. Can you please check the versions of Chrome on both scenarios? 
I know its a long shot, but if the "broken" one is running a very old version, say bellow 14 from around 2011, according to the [chrome version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history) - this just might be it

BTW, which server are you using?

Comment: Unbelievable :) Most of the chrome installation where a variation of versions 13 and 29; I asked IT and this was possible since machines were denied internet access (and thus could not automatically update). Versions 13 indeed were the ones returning the error... Thanks a lot!